# Influxdb ignore duplicates by tags when insert

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I have several threads writing data in influxdb.

The data can be duplicated in the sense of tag.

The db is similar to below.
Here, "name" is fields, "uique_id" is tags

| time | name | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-02 17:00:08.998 | Alice | 10001 |
| 2021-03-02 14:00:10.991 | Bob | 995 |

When I try to insert

| time | name | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-02 17:00:09.002 | Alice | 10001 |

the db successfully inserts.

I understand if the tag **and** time is the same, the db **overwrites**.

However, I want to discard the new data since the unique_id 1001 is already in the db.

My first attempt was to check if the unique_id exists with select before inserting.

`select * from dbname where unique_id=10001`

But I'm using several threads, so it doesn't work because another thread can write in between the select and insert.

Are there anyway to achieve the purpose using Influxdb?

Thank you in advance.